# Is it inappropriate to offer to train a superior when they express they don't know something that you do?

Tags: manager, education, skills, training

They didn't specifically request to be trained. However, they have quite often asked "how do you do this?" questions, and many times, telling how to do something doesn't make sense without knowledge of some principles and history.

And you know for sure that training them will ultimately benefit the company.

How do you tell them that you're willing to offer help beyond "this is how you do something" without sounding too, well, superior? Should I even bother with this?

Comment: Hmm, without more details.  ...I'd just wait for them to ask for that training. Management will say "my job is Management"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with explaining the reasons you do what you... as long as you don't tell them that's the only way to do things.

Answer (score 5):

If there are other people in your company who would *also* benefit from it, you can offer to lead an informal, optional class/workshop.  This allows your boss to attend (along with others) without any loss of face; if it would be embarrassing for him to look like he doesn't know this, well, he's there to check out what his underling is doing.  I've done this a few times -- including picking up some people who I didn't know were interested in the topic.  I've had the most success when I've cast this as a discussion or a workshop, keeping open the possibility that other attendees will also know some of this and have useful things to contribute.

If it's something where your boss is the only who who doesn't know this (and should), that approach won't work.  The last time I was in that situation I said (privately and verbally, not in email) something like "hey, I know that $technology can be a little confusing if you aren't in there using it every day, and if you'd like, I'd be happy to sit down with you for an hour and show you some tricks".  When we had that discussion I interspersed "background/model" stuff with actual usage tips.

Answer (score 2):

Be nice and the next time they ask a question, offer that you are more than willing to sit down with them for a set amount of time to teach them. Do not necessarily give them all the answers, but teaching your co-workers and supervisors helps show that you have leadership qualities and are willing to help others.

Which looks very good in all employers' eyes.

Answer (score -6):

Keep it to yourself.  If you're smarter than your boss, and it's known publicly, it can cause a lot of tension in the workplace because people will start to come to you instead of the appointed leader.  Some bosses become VERY insecure in this type of situation.

Don't volunteer so much; just pretend you're stupid unless you're asked.

Comment: -1 *...just pretend you're stupid unless you're asked.* Seriously?

Comment: Good bosses surround themselves with smart people. If they need training they will usually request it, but often are quite happy to let their direct reports take care of tasks while they focus on their management responsibilties. Pretending your stupid is not great career advice.

Comment: Every boss ain't a good boss. THAT's the point.

Comment: I would not want to pretend to be stupid. That has its own problems. I don't like to regard myself as smarter than the boss, but it's a good point, though, that we should be careful not to infringe on a superior's role.